# Odd behaviour of width(auto) when words has auto break lines

Tags: css

Consider the following example:

https://jsfiddle.net/3w4fx8vu/

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 500px;
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">text text text</div>
  <div class="child">text text text</div>
  <div class="child">text text text</div>
  <div class="child">text text text text</div>
  <div class="child">text text text</div>
  <div class="child">text text text</div>
  <div class="child">text text text</div>
  <div class="child">text text text</div>
</div>
```

The forth element (with 4 words) has an extra space from the right. The question is: why is this happens and what are the workarounds this?

Answer (score 1):

does this work for you?  We added white-space:nowrap and overflow:hidden

It's not entirely clear what you want to happen when the text overflows the container;

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 500px;
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">text text text</div>
  <div class="child">text text text</div>
  <div class="child">text text text</div>
  <div class="child">text text text text</div>
  <div class="child">text text text</div>
  <div class="child">text text text</div>
  <div class="child">text text text</div>
  <div class="child">text text text</div>
</div>
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;      
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">text text text</div>
  <div class="child">text text text</div>
  <div class="child">text text text</div>
  <div class="child">text text text text</div>
  <div class="child">text text text</div>
  <div class="child">text text text</div>
  <div class="child">text text text</div>
  <div class="child">text text text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is more of a comment than answer

Comment: I want it to fit the content. The max-width of the container is there to replicate the problem: when the words of the item are in two or more rows, the element doesn't get the width by its content and has extra space from a side.

Comment: I want it to fit by the content, but with "natural" word splitting. So, if the container is small, it should adapt to the width... Am I explaining this clear? :\

Comment: no, can you show us a sketch of what you would like to see?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify any width to the container , to make them take the same width you can add : `flex: 1 1 ;` : https://jsfiddle.net/9gf8a7rm/

```
html, body {margin:0; padding:0;}
.parent {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 500px;
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
}
.child {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  flex: 1 1 ;
}
```

the width of the parent is limited , so you can't see the changes unless you remove : `width:500px` you can also replace it by `max-width:fit-content` to make it only take what it needs , see : https://jsfiddle.net/9gf8a7rm/1/

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want the same width. I want width to fit the content,

Comment: the width of the parent is limited , so you can't see the changes unless you remove : `width:500px`

Answer (score 0):

**Why this happens ?**

By default a flex item has

```
flex-grow:0;
flex-shrink:1;
flex-basis:auto;
```

**flex-grow:0;** Means if there's left over space inside the container the elements won't grow.

**flex-shrink:1;** Means If there isn't enough space inside the container elements will shrink to fit inside

**flex-basis:auto;** Means flex item will have a minimum width/height equal to content.

With that setup, Elements content will be laid out **First** then if there's left over space it will be distributed evenly.

Now huge elements will take more space for themselves and still take their portion of the left over space that has been split evenly on all elements.

The existences of a huge element will force elements to shrink thanks to `flex-shrink:1;` and that is why you see one element have more space than the others.

---

**What are the workarounds this?**

```
flex-grow:1;
flex-shrink:0;
flex-basis:0;
```

**flex-grow:1;** Grow to fit makes elements share space equally.

**flex-shrink:0;** Never shrink

**flex-basis:0;** Split available space **first**, Then lay down the content.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 500px;
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  flex: 1 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">text text text</div>
  <div class="child">text text text</div>
  <div class="child">text text text</div>
  <div class="child">text text text text</div>
  <div class="child">text text text</div>
  <div class="child">text text text</div>
  <div class="child">text text text</div>
  <div class="child">text text text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So there's no way to fit it by the content?

Comment: @veyogi8205 There's no magic in CSS, Just think about it, How can you fit two things where one is wider than the other ?

Comment: I think about it and it doesn't sound logical. More over, I can prove you're wrong, take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/y4gtr2qL/2/

Comment: What you exactly proving wrong ? That code and the one in this question is totally different.

Comment: How is that "totally different"? :|

Comment: @veyogi8205 What is that code supposed to represent ?

Comment: To prove that what you assume is wrong, and more exactly the following: "How can you fit two things where one is wider than the other". Or at least that how I see it, maybe I'm wrong :)

Comment: I still don't understand what you think i assumed or what is wrong, All i said in the answer is quoted from the spec. Your code different Because you forcing line breaks that tells the browser exactly where to wrap so it knows where to wrap elements without leaving trailing space.

Comment: on the other hand, use `text-align:justify;`

Comment: Or `flex-basis:calc(100% / 8);` 8 being the number of elements if you know how many you'll have, but if there isn't enough space in the container elements will overflow. Other than this i'm not sure what you're after.